# How to check if column values of a dataframe are equal and concatenate column indexes-values if they are

Tags: python, dataframe

If for example i have the following dataframe,

```
    Id  D1      D2      D3      D4
    0   8224    8224    8224    8224
    1   9999999 9999999 9999999 9999999
    2   161870  161870  161870  161870
```

and since these columns contain the same values i want to remake
the dataframe into this

```
    Id  1-2-3-4
    0   8224    
    1   9999999 
    2   161870
```

I have managed to make it work but i feel my way is too slow and messy.
Is there an elegant and fast way to make this ?

In case Col-2 for example was different the df would look like this

```
    Id  1-3-4    2
    0   8224     8225
    1   9999999  9999999
    2   161870   15881
```

So in the end it is a grouping of the col indexes when the col values are the same.

```
eg Id 1-3-4 2-5-6-7 8-10 9
```

Comment: What happens if, for a single row, 2 columns are not equal (say 1 & 3)?

Comment: Can you post your "slow and messy" way please? It might be that what you have now is as good as it gets!

Comment: Will do tomorrow when i am back at work. Hopefully this wont get lost by then